# Databricks: Cluster vs Data warehouse - Why do I need data warehouse

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

I am working with Azure databricks. I am using notebook to write down all my spark related code and sql queries without any issue. I created some hive tables and I can run sql queries against those hive tables in notebook.

I don't see  need for using Data warehouse. When I search on web about when should I use cluster or Data warehouse, all I get is the difference between the two and almost every link talk about Data warehouses are used to run SQL workload and no one talks about any specific use case or work load when I should prefer one over another.

Moreover after going through all that stuff, I am more confused when they say Data warehouses are used to run SQL workload because I am able to run SQL using cluster as well.

My question is, when should I think about using the Data warehouse rather than cluster? Are data warehouses meant for any specific use case or workload? Is there a scenario when I would need both cluster and data warehouse?

Comment: Please clarify the data warehouse.

Answer (score -1):

Databricks SQL Analytics is a great choice for users who primarily work with SQL and need a simplified, interactive, and optimized querying experience. On the other hand, Databricks clusters are ideal for data engineers and data scientists who require flexibility, scalability, and the ability to run a wide range of workloads beyond SQL queries.

The choice between SQL Analytics and Databricks clusters depends on your team's roles, the nature of your workloads, and your organization's specific requirements. In many cases, organizations use both tools in conjunction to cover a wide spectrum of data processing and analytics needs.

important thing Serverless compute capability in sql warehouse has lot of advantages :  https://docs.databricks.com/en/serverless-compute/index.html